# Windows batch script to name files after containing subfolder and copy to root

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-rename, batch-rename

consider following folder structure:

```
root
  Folder1
    file1.txt
    file2.dat
  Folder2
    file3.doc
    file4.pdf
  rename.bat
```

I want to rename the files (using rename.bat) according to the name of the respective subdirectories, copy them to the root directory and delete the subfolders so that I get

```
root
  Folder1.txt
  Folder1.dat
  Folder2.doc
  Folder2.pdf
  rename.bat
```

Actually I know this is possible (and actually with very few lines of code) since I already found the code somewhere some time ago. Sadly I lost my scipt and am not able to find the code again now.

Regards,
Eduard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers!

I improved upon your code to work as intended so it perfectly fit my needs now:

```
@echo off
for /d %%a in (*) do (
  cd "%%a"
  for %%b in (*) do (
    echo moving "%%a\%%b" to "%%a%%~xb"
    move "%%b" "..\%%a%%~xb"
  )
  cd ..
  rd "%%a"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I made this my self. I created a similar situation to yours and it worked fine for me. However you have to specify the location to copy all the files to.

```
for /d %%a in (*) do (
cd %%a
for /r %%b in (*) do (
copy %%b C:\ [root] \%%a%%~xb
)
cd..
)
pause
```

Hopes this helps.

Yours Mona.

Answer (score 0):

This uses Mona's code but handles long filenames.  Test it on some sample folders.

Call it renfolder.bat or something as rename.bat uses the name of an internal command.

```
@echo off
for /d %%a in (*) do (
cd "%%a"
for %%b in (*) do (
echo copying "%%a%%~xb"
copy "%%b" "\%%a%%~xb" >nul
)
cd..
rd "%%a"
)
pause
```